# Retrieve URL from a link that was created by CTRL+K and not a Hyperlink formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of cells that contain strings that were converted to links using CTRL+K
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Afshcs8f0A3CTeTPaudAhxZVYjMP22KY2gtLeu5qmAs/edit#gid=0
How can I retrieve the URLs in each of these cells?
If it was a formula (i.e. Hyperlink) I could use FormulaText to do so, but it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You would need Apps Script for this

Specifically the [`getRichTextValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue) function:

```
let richText = cellRange.getRichTextValue();
let link = richText.getLinkUrl();
```

I did some experiments to see if it could be written as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) so that you could use it like any old formula, i.e. `=getHyperlink(A1)` however, *when you pass in a range to a custom function, the **value** of the cell, the contents, gets passed to the function, not the address*. There may be a funky workaround in this [WebApps Exchange thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-to-pass-a-range-into-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheets) but depending on what you need it for, it may not be needed.

You could write a function like this:

```js
function getHyperlink(cellReference) {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getRange(cellReference);
  
  let richText = range.getRichTextValue();
  let link = richText.getLinkUrl();

  return link;
}
```

Which you could call from another function like this:

```
let aLink = getHyperlink("A1");
```

**NOTE** - the speech brackets around the cell reference.

If you use it as-is as a custom function, you would need to pass in the cell reference as TEXT (you would need to make sure you run the script once from the editor first, to ensure that it has been authorized).

[image]

#### EDIT:

Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, but you could use this custom formula as-is in combination with [`=CELL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en), to make it work like a formula should.

```
=getHyperlink(CELL("address", A2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried running an Apps Script with the code you've added but I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
getHyperlink @ Code.gs:4

I have zero experience with Apps Script so I might be missing on something trivial. Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: It could be many things but first thing that comes to mind is to check that this line `"let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");"` actually refers to the proper sheet name, i.e. replace `"Sheet1"` with the sheet name. Also make sure you are passing in a reference to a cell enclosed in `" "`

Comment: Thanks. The sheet is indeed Sheet1.
I've added ';' at the end of lines 6,7 and 9 which helped a bit. I've also changed "cellreference' in line 4 to 'A2'. 
Now I can save and run the function, but whenever I run the function in the spreedsheet (e.g. =getHyperlink(A4)) it brings the link from cell A2. 
How can I make the cell location be determined by the function?

Comment: @Tom Changing line 4 to `A2` is hard-coding it to always return `A2`, change it back to `cellReference`. That said, I've thought of something to make this work better - I've updated my answer.

Comment: First of all, it worked - thanks a lot! Strange thing, before I hard coded it to 'A2' there was an error that it was missing a range. I switched it to 'A2', it saved, then switched it back to cellReference and it started working. In any case, cool solution, thanks!